# VS-2012 Express web Add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

Is this possible to make add-in application in VS2012-express?
I am going to try nuget.

Comment: add-in application which is allow integrate with Visual Studio..

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible.  Visual Studio Express SKUs don't support 3rd party Add-In / Extensions.  This is a limitation set by Microsoft and can't be overridden by developers.

Note: Express SKUs do support extensions which are project templates.  These have no real functionality though and just exist for creating new projects.

Comment: but i heard that "NuGet" is helpful to make third-party add-in/extension,is it?

Comment: NuGet does not create addins/extensions, it allows you to create and share libraries to be used in code.